# Unable to Save Files Directly to SharePoint Library Outside of MS Office

Tags: 2013, document-library, workspace, sharepoint-workspace

I've been banging my head against my desk for a while now with and figured I'd see if someone wiser here has any insight. I'm trying to save files directly to a SharePoint library.

I have the library mapped as a network drive, as well as created a link to it in my Favorites in Explorer (along with connecting to it via SharePoint Work space).  When I browse to it via Explorer it shows up fine.

[image: Workspace Available]

I can open/save files from MS Office applications just fine, but when I try to File> Save As from another application (such as Adobe), my Explorer window won't show that my Workspaces even exist.
[image: Workspace Missing]

Trying a different way, if I browse to the site Library in the Save As window (using a shortcut to the file path I created beforehand) I get the error:

> "The specified network name is no longer available."

Anyone have any thoughts on what else could be going on here? Running SharePoint 2013 on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can save file to SharePoint from any other application other than office or MS applications. 
The best thing to try is map a folder to the SharePoint folder location. Open the folder in explorer view save the address and map  a new folder to that location and try save your file to that mapped folder. 
I have tried in past to save the file from any other application other than MS but it never worked for me as well.